# Vue: Empty object property

Tags: javascript, rest, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component to which I pass data to via a method:

```
<div class="component-form" v-if="component">
    <render-component class="component-form__render-view"></render-component>
    <form-sidebar
      class="component-form__sidebar"
      :component="formatData()"
    >
    </form-sidebar>
</div>
```

This is said method (located in, well, `methods`):

```
formatData: function () {
  const componentObject = {
    ID: this.component.ID,
    Title: this.component.Title,
    Groups: []
  }

  for (let object in this.component.ParametersSpec) {
    let actualObject = this.component.ParametersSpec[object]
    actualObject.Title = object

    if (!componentObject.Groups[actualObject.group]) {
      componentObject.Groups[actualObject.group] = []
    }

    componentObject.Groups[actualObject.group].push(actualObject)
    console.log(componentObject)
  }

  return componentObject
}
```

FormatData is dependent on an API request:

```
mounted () {
api.components(routes.COMPONENT_API_URL).getOne({id: this.id})
  .then(response => { this.component = response.data })
},
```

Then in this `form-sidebar` component, I just have a simple `{{ component }}` to display the contents. The following is the output:

`{ "ID": "service-pit", "Title": "Service Pit", "Groups": [] }`

But, Groups is empty, which it shouldn't be, and certainly isn't in the console. Now I know this is a common symptom of passing data before it is properly returned. Since the console also says groups is empty before I open it (then it rechecks the contents and finds out it isn't).

But if the request wasn't finished yet, then how did it display the ID and Title correctly? And how can I make Vue update the data when the request is done?

Comment: Did u define component in data section? If so - how?

Comment: @Aldarund I just returned `component: undefined`

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats - check this

Comment: can you upload your code to somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const componentObject = {
    ID: this.component.ID,
    Title: this.component.Title,
    Groups: []
  }
```

had to be:

```
const componentObject = {
    ID: this.component.ID,
    Title: this.component.Title,
    Groups: {}
  }
```

This took way too long for such a small problem..